# Export Java code to CSV and import in Excel 2013

Tags: java, excel, csv

I export Java source code to a CSV file. Because Java code can contain a lot of normal separators, I used ´ as separator (is there a better one for Java?).

One of my exported data rows looks like this in the output file:

```
2.0´"if (x < 1) {
  System.out.println(x + x);
  if (x < 2) {
    System.out.println("xy");
  }
}"
```

But when I import this into excel, what happens is that the first System.out until the end of the actual row (`"`) will land in the second row. I also tried omitting the `"` in the second column.

The String generated by Java for the second column is

```
condStr = ((IfStatement) cond.getOriginalNode()).toString();
```

I think this is a problem of Excel, as my CSV file looks fine. What can I change to make it be imported properly in Excel (2013)?

Comment: I'd have to look it up but the problem might be that Excel can't process the line breaks correctly. You might have to replace them with what Excel can read, so maybe you can create an Excel file having a cell which contains line breaks and export that to CSV. Then read it back in and if Excel reads the cell correctly, check how Excel actually exported the line breaks (might be just `\r` or `\n` or some other markup).

Comment: I looked up some of our code and we replace line breaks, i.e. `\r\n` or `\r` with just `\n` within cells, so that's what you might have to do - I can't check that right now.

Comment: `\n` is the only linebreak I add in Java anyway (not 100% sure though what IfStatement does in it's `toString()` - how can I check?

Comment: @dasLort Open the file with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and "show all characters" (this includes line breaks). Other editors can probably do that, but that's the one I use most. By the way, my Excel 2010 can open CSV files with multiline fields, enclosed in double quotes. Line breaks are CRLF. How do you tell Excel that "´" is a separator?

Comment: Also, another problem will necessarily arise: there are double quotes in Java, and there are in you example. Excel will misinterpret your file anyway. And yet another possible problem, bear in mind that Excel (2010) cells are limited to 32767 characters (probably less on earlier versions). While it's quite large, a Java program may be larger.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it shows "LF" in the end of every row. Is that the thing I need for excel? You can tell excel if you import data and then chose separated instead of fixed. Then on the next page it shows you to choose your own separators.

Comment: @dasLort After some tests, the problem is not the LF, but the import as "separated". While Excel can successfuly import multiline CSV files, it can't import multiline separated files (or at least I failed to do so).

Answer (score 0):

You need `\r\n` at each end of line in the CSV file. Quotes inside the text should be escaped with double quotes. If you choose the semicolon as field separator, you can open the file directly with Excel (file extension `*.csv` should be bound to Excel).

Here is a small example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class CsvTest {

  /**
   * CSV quote 
   *  
   * @param fieldContent String to quote
   * @param sep Field separator
   * @param quote Text quote character
   * @param target Target (e.g. StringBuilder or Writer)
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private static void quote(CharSequence fieldContent, char sep, char quote, Appendable target) throws IOException {
    target.append(quote);

    // Escape the quoting character. 
    final int len = fieldContent.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      final char c = fieldContent.charAt(i);
      if(c == quote) {
        target.append(quote).append(quote);
      } else {
        target.append(c);
      }
    }

    target.append(quote);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final char sep = ';';
    final char quote = '"';
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    quote("2.0", sep, quote, sb);
    sb.append(sep);
    quote("if (x < 1) {\r\n" + 
        "  System.out.println(x + x);\r\n" + 
        "  if (x < 2) {\r\n" + 
        "    System.out.println(\"xy\");\r\n" + 
        "  }\r\n" + 
        "}", sep, quote, sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Resulting in

```
"2.0";"if (x < 1) {
  System.out.println(x + x);
  if (x < 2) {
    System.out.println(""xy"");
  }
}"
```